# Build M1 binary for Kotlin Native in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, apple-m1, arm64, kotlin-native

I'm playing with Kotlin Native on my M1 Mac using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 Community Edition. (Build #IC-223.7571.182, built on November 29, 2022; Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.14 aarch64)

I noticed that the resulting binaries are for x86_64

I can't find in the settings, the IDEA help, or Google how to get it to build for aarch64.

Is it missing or am I just not finding the setting?

[image: The Kotlin Compiler page of my project settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have not found a way to set this via the GUI and I don't have a Java, Kotlin, Gradle, or JetBrains background, but I found out how to change it in the configuration files for now:

[image: Project and editor tabs for the fix]

In the project tab I can edit `build.gradle.kts` and change the `kotlin`/`nativeTarget`/`hostOS` line:

Was:

```
hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
```

Now:

```
hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosArm64("native")
```

Thanks to the help of this post on YouTrack from a month ago: [New Kotlin Multiplatform Native Application project template won't run on Apple M1 from IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-23555/)

Comment: That's confusing…  It hasn't been called ‘Mac OS X’ for over a decade!  (It was renamed to ‘OS X’ in 2011 with 10.8 Mountain Lion, and then ‘macOS’ in 2016 with 10.12 Sierra.)

Comment: @gidds fortunately that line was already there and the part I had to change brought up the list of options so I didn't have to make a bunch of guesses.

Comment: @gidds Apparently it's "macos" on "X64" architecture, where "X64" means 64-bit X86.